# Add className to first div of an array in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a className to the first div of an array I'm mapping over in React.  I'm new to react so the syntax is stumping me.

Here's my initial state:

```
export default class EventList extends Component {


  state = {
    users: [],
    events: [],
    shownForm: null,
    hideNewForm: true,
    hideEditForm: true,
    currentUserId: this.props.getCurrentUser(),
    editTitle: "",
    editDate: "",
    editSynopsis: "",
    editLocation: "",
    editId: ""
  }
```

This is a non-functioning function but how I'm trying to think of using a conditional statement for the array:

```
addFirstClass =() => {
    if(this.state.events === this.state.events[0]){
    className = "card-body details"
    }else{
    className = "card-body details coral"
    }
  }
```

Here's where I'm rendering the divs to the DOM:

```
render() {
return(   
<section className="events">
   {this.state.events.map(event => (
      <div key={event.id} className="card">
        <div className={this.addFirstClass()}>
          <p className="card-details">
           Synopsis:{event.synopsis}</p> 
        </div>
       </div>
</section>
    )
   }
```

I've searched other threads but I can't seem to figure out how to make this work.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic className, I hope this work

```
<section className="events">
   {this.state.events.map(event => (
      <div key={event.id} className={this.state.events[0].id === event.id ? 'card-body details' : 'card-body details coral'}>
        <div className={this.addFirstClass()}>
          <p className="card-details">
           Synopsis:{event.synopsis}</p> 
        </div>
       </div>
</section>
```

`<div key={event.id} className={this.state.events[0].id === event.id ? 'card-body details' : 'card-body details coral'}>`

Here I'm using JavaScript shorthand if, that check if `this.state.events[0].id` equal current `event.id` add this classes else add another classes

Comment: Brilliant!  This helped me alot!  I hope to be better about thinking through syntax one day.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (use the built-in counter in map and ask if counter is 0 ... else ...):

```
 <section className="events">
   {this.state.events.map((event, i) => (
      <div key={event.id} className={i===0 ? 'card-body details' : 'card-body details coral'}>
        <div className={this.addFirstClass()}>
          <p className="card-details">
           Synopsis:{event.synopsis}</p> 
        </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Or a kind of opposite and a bit more smooth:

```
 <section className="events">
   {this.state.events.map((event, i) => (
      <div key={event.id} className={'card-body details' + (i !== 0 ? ' coral' : '')}>
        <div className={this.addFirstClass()}>
          <p className="card-details">
           Synopsis:{event.synopsis}</p> 
        </div>
   </div>
</section>
```